# Possible to pass a google.visualization.Query into the google.maps.FusionTablesLayer constructor?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

The constructor for `google.maps.FusionTablesLayer` takes a `query` parameter, which contains the same information as can be found in a `google.visualization.Query`, as I understand it.

I have some code which constructs a `FusionTablesLayer` (which will submit a query to the API) and some other code that fetches data based on a `Query`. This will, I think, result in two GET requests for the same data. I think it's best if I try to avoid this double-query if I can.

Any ideas on how to do this? If I could construct a `Query` and pass it into the constructor for `FusionTablesLayer` somehow, that might work. But the two documentation pages don't reference each other.

**EDIT**

I should add that in the case I'm working with, Google is actually constructing the map tiles on the server. I did try pulling down the polygons and working with them but the data was massive. If you are thinking of doing anything along these lines, I suggest you don't do it in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you are dealing with the same data, the two concepts are very different. When you use a `google.visualization.Query`, you actually transfer raw data from a Fusion Table to the client. Normally you would use this data for a visualization of any kind.

When you specify a query for `google.maps.FusionTablesLayer` you can only get the location column. And this data is not raw, it is already wrapped in a layer which you can add to a map.  That's basically it. You can add some styling and define what other data you want to display in the info window, but that's it.

It's maybe a little bit misleading that they both are called `query`, but actually they are very different.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. I assumed that the visualisation was using a query internally and then parsing it to create tiles / overlay in JS. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Joe if my answer helped you, you should consider to accept it ;)

Comment: I was waiting for someone to come along and solve all my problems, but it looks like you're correct. Thanks!